# Newline character different than system newline

Tags: java, string, newline, inputstream

**My Question:** How do I force an input stream to process line separators as the system standard line separator?

I read a file to a string and the newlines get converted to `\n` but my `System.getProperty("line.separator");` is `\r\n`. I want this to be [portable](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=38), so I want my file reader to read the newlines as the system standard newline character (whatever that may be). How can I force it? Here are my methods from the [Java Helper](http://www.github.com/kentcdodds/Java-Helper) Library to read the file in as a string.

```
/**
* Takes the file and returns it in a string. Uses UTF-8 encoding
*
* @param fileLocation
* @return the file in String form
* @throws IOException when trying to read from the file
*/
public static String fileToString(String fileLocation) throws IOException {
  InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileLocation), "UTF-8");
  return readerToString(streamReader);
}

/**
* Returns all the lines in the Reader's stream as a String
*
* @param reader
* @return
* @throws IOException when trying to read from the file
*/
public static String readerToString(Reader reader) throws IOException {
  StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
  char[] buffer = new char[1024];
  int length;
  while ((length = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    stringWriter.write(buffer, 0, length);
  }
  reader.close();
  stringWriter.close();
  return stringWriter.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `readerToString` method doesn't do *anything* to line endings. It simply copies character data - that's all. It's entirely unclear how you're diagnosing the problem, but that code really *doesn't* change `\n` to `\r\n`. It must be `\r\n` in the file - which you should look at in a hex editor. What created the file in the first place? You should look there for how any line breaks are represented.

If you want to read lines, use `BufferedReader.readLine()` which will cope with `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n`.

Note that [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) has a lot of helpful methods for reading all the data from readers, as well as splitting a reader into lines etc.

Comment: I'm liking this answer/explanation. Thanks. Quick question. I'm trying to implement this and I want it to use `UTF-8` encoding. Should I just wrap what I have in a `BufferedReader` or would there be a better way to do it? My implementation would be like this: `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileLocation), "UTF-8"));`

Comment: @kentcdodds: That seems reasonable to me - although as I say, Guava can probably make it simpler. (In particular, you can specify `Charsets.UTF_8` to get rid of the string literal from your code...)

Comment: Thanks for the help Jon. **Note for future readers** If this weren't a self-development project I would go with the suggestion of the Guava library.

Answer (score 2):

It's advisable to use [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) for reading a file line-by-line in a portable way, and then you can use each of the lines read for writing to the required output using the line separator of your choice

Answer (score 1):

With the [Scanner#useDelimiter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.lang.String%29) method you can specify what delimiter to use when reading from a `File` or `InputStream` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a BufferedReader to read the file line by line and convert the line separators, e.g.:

```
public static String readerToString(Reader reader) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    StringBuffer stringBuf = new StringBuffer();
    String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    String line = null;

    while ((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
      stringBuf.append(line).append(separator);
    }
    bufReader.close();
    return stringBuf.toString();
}
```